# Getting Null Pointer Exception while running a test through TestNG

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, opencsv

I am using CSV reader to fetch the data from and using this data in a test function using DataProvider.

***`TestNG Method`***

```
@Test(dataProvider = "regCSVData", dataProviderClass = LoginData.class)
public void testLoginUsingCSVFile(LoginData loginData){
    driver.get(appURL);
    Login login = PageFactory.initElements(driver, Login.class);
    login.loginToFwbm(loginData);
}
```

***`LoginData Class`***

```
@DataProvider(name = "regCSVData")
public static Object[][] getCSVData() throws IOException {
    CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(
            LoginData.class.getResource("/regdata.csv").getPath()));
    List<String[]>dataList = csvReader.readAll();
    Object[][]data = new Object[dataList.size()][1];
    List<LoginData> logList = new ArrayList<LoginData>();
    for (String[] strArray:dataList){
        LoginData loginData = new LoginData();
        loginData.setUserName(strArray[0].trim());
        loginData.setPassword(strArray[1].trim());
        logList.add(loginData);
    }
    for (int i=0; i<data.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<data[i].length;j++){
            data[i][j] = logList.get(i);
        }
    }
    csvReader.close();
    return data;
}
```

***`CSV File`***

```
asdf, pa2
qwerty, pa2
john, pa2
```

When I run this test using TestNG, I am getting Null Pointer exception

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:161)
        at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:429)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleParameters(Invoker.java:1383)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.createParameters(Invoker.java:1075)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1180)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
        at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
        at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
        at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
        at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
        at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.fwbm.dataobject.LoginData.getCSVData(LoginData.java:49)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
        at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:135)
        ... 20 more
```

***`Project Structure Image`***

[image]

Comment: Which is line 49 in LoginData?

Comment: LoginData.class.getResource("/regdata.csv").getPath()));

Comment: I've put the csv file under project name... so it is coming directly under project name...it isn't kept inside any folder... so I am directly using it name to refer it.

Comment: Looks like the file `regdata.csv` is not found.

Comment: even I think, it is not able to find regdata.csv but I didn't understand why? :( ... I've added the image of project structure as well... if it helps.

Comment: this file must be added to the classpath. Is it in the classPath?

Comment: No, its not there in classpath.. how do I add it? and why do we need to add it in classpath... .can't we directly use it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54452/discussion-between-jens-and-paras).

Comment: @pArAs what if you'll try `getResource("regdata.csv")`, without slash

Comment: Jens helped me out.. its working now! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the file to the classPath in your "run configuration". Then the file can be loaded using getRessource();

Answer (score 1):

The best way to use QAF. In QAF, you don't need to provide implementation for parse data provider file. It is very much easy for you to use it.

You can refer documentation from [QAF Data Driven](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/maketest_data_driven.html)